# when is next elections

Tags: discussion, election

I see there are elections going on different SO sites and just wondering if there going to be any elections for SE too.

I would also like to know, whats the criteria for being a nomination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the SE sites don't get together and have elections at the same time; an individual site will have elections if it gets busy enough that it needs more mods. SO tends to have them at least once a year, and in this case [one of their mods](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50049/tim-post) was hired to work at Stack Exchange, so they're down a person

The criteria for being a moderator is on the right side of the nomination page. SO is harder than most other sites; they require 3000 reputation and a handful of badges. For [Sharepoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=nomination) it's just:

> any community member in good standing with more than **300** reputation